# Show progress while rendering fractals in multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, progress-bar

Hello,

I'm currently writing a fractal explorer/generator and I'm stuck with implementing a progress bar. Currently I have an abstract class `Renderer` that inherits a render method `public abstract long render(int[] pixels, int w, int h);`. This method returns the number of iterations.

An example of a `Renderer` class would be `BuddhaRenderer`, here's an excerpt from the `render()`method of `BuddhaRenderer`:

```
int[] numHits = new int[w * h];

ArrayList<BuddhaThread> threads = new ArrayList<BuddhaThread>();

for (int i = 0; i < controller.processors; i ++) {
    BuddhaThread th = new BuddhaThread(controller, w, h, numHits, anti);
    th.start();
    threads.add(th);
}

try {
    for(Thread th : threads)
        th.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will start multiple threads that will write their results into `numHits`. I'm waiting for all threads to finish before continuing with drawing the image when running the `join()` method for all threads.

Now, how would I go about displaying a progress bar of all those threads either inside the same JFrame or inside a different JFrame without the progress bar freezing?

The progress in those could be read reliably since they just iterate over a given amount of random points.

This is my first time using threads so please feel free to correct me If I'm doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: I'd have the worker threads increment a shared counter as they went along, and I'd have a javax.swing.Timer that periodically updated the progress bar based on the current value of the counter and the expected final value.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've just tried it and I think it would work like a charm, wouldn't it be for the my frame not responding while rendering. The JProgressBar only gets updated when the calculations are already done. Any suggestion as to how to handle this?

Comment: [`Benojt`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/benojt/?source=directory) is a complete example.